# how do I prove the following set is open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint closed sets in $(X,d)$.

define $U=\{x\in X | d(x,A)<d(x,B)\}$.

how do I prove that $U$ is open in $(X,d)$?

Comment: Hint: Can you prove $d(x,A)$ and $d(x,B)$ are continuous functions?

Comment: yes. but I'm not sure where this is leading to

Comment: Hmm, if $f\colon X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, what can you say about $\{x\in X: f(x)>0\}$?

Comment: then I know this set is open because it is equal to $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ but I'm not sure how can I write my set as a preimage

Comment: Put my two hints together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subset $Y \subset X$, the map $x \to d(x, Y)$ is continuous. Therefore the map $\varphi : x \to d(x, B) - d(x, A)$ is also continuous. Finally, $U$ which is the inverse image of the open set $(0,\infty)$ under the continuous map $\varphi$ is open.

Comment: You need $(-\infty,0)$ instead, I think.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for reading the answer in details and noticing the typo. I'll edit my answer.